# Grouping rows by Max column value per row

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a many to many table which has repeating values of `student_id`, `gradelevel_id` and `schoolyear_id`. So my goal is to display records of the *most recent schoolyear* and *last gradelevel taken*. In other words, the last `grade_level` taken by student.

**schoolyear_student_lt** (MANY TO MANY table)

[image: MANY TO MANY table]

**gradelevel_mt**

[image: GRADE LEVEL MASTER TABLE]

**schoolyear_mt**

[image: SCHOOL YEAR MASTER TABLE]

So is should display 1 unique `student_id`, 1 `grade_level`, 1 `schoolyear` per row on the result set.

I created a stored procedure.

```
    SELECT sslt.gradelevel_id,sy.schoolyear_id, sslt.student_id,MAX(gl.grade_level) 
    FROM gradelevel_mt gl
    INNER JOIN schoolyear_student_lt sslt ON gl.gradelevel_id = sslt.gradelevel_id
    INNER JOIN schoolyear_mt sy ON sslt.schoolyear_id = sy.schoolyear_id
    WHERE gl.gradelevel_id = sslt.gradelevel_id
    GROUP BY sslt.student_id;
```

But problem is, my stored procedure returns incorrect `schoolyear_id` and `gradelevel_id`. Only the `student_id` and `MAX(gl.gradelevel)` are correct.

[image]

The correct expected result set should be

```
gradelevel_id | schoolyear_id | student_id | MAX(gl.gradelevel) | 
302             401             20170008      1 
304             404             20170009      3
```

For `student_id`: **20170008** it should be `gradelevel_id`: `302 (Grade 1)` and `schoolyear_id` : `401 (2016-2017)` **not** `402(2015-2016)`.

For `student_id`: **20170009** it should be `gradelevel_id`: `304 (Grade 3)` and `schoolyear_id` : `404 (2019-2020)` **not** `402(2015-2016)`.

I hope my explanation is clear. I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you can use IsActive=1 filed in schoolyear_mt table.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @p3ace please provide create table statements and insert statements for your data.. make a export not screenshots with the data, nobody is able to help you

Comment: This is a faq, please google re stackoverflow sql max within group. You want to maximize a certain function of grade & year.